# How to insert an image into Generic.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using the generic.xaml to create a master page for an application I am creating, here is the code so far:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Master}">                   
                <StackPanel>
                    <Menu Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Panel.ZIndex="0">
                        <Menu.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFB3DDF2" Offset="1.0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD6E9F4" Offset="0.0"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Menu.Background>
                    </Menu>                       
                    <Menu Width="350" Height="850" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Panel.ZIndex="0">
                        <Menu.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFD6E9F4" Offset="1.0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Menu.Background>
                    </Menu> 
                </StackPanel>                                                            
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to add an image to this page, I have tried many methods but can't find the correct one. Some methods will bring the image in but will remove one of my other menus.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in your project and set its build action to `Resource` then reference it in this way:

```
<Image Source="/YourApplicatioName;component/PathToYourImage/Image.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when you say "Put it in the project" do you mean my Generic.xaml page code?

Comment: @user2979423 No I mean directly inside the project, simply drag&drop the image in the application project